# Stop overwriting addresses in vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, stdvector, c++98

My problem is along the following lines. I have a vector class elementList which contains elements describing triangles along a surface, but when I add individually constructed elements into elementList via emplace_back, their address changes.

If you need more code let me know, but I removed the fluff to get what I think are the essentials. First elementList:

```
class elementList
{
public:
    elementList(std::string filename);

    std::vector<element> const& get_elements() const;

private:
    std::vector<element> m_elements;
};
```

and I parse information from a source txt file into it. The element class, excluding some unnecessary bits, looks like this

```
class element
{
public:

    element(float x11, float x12, float x21, float x22, float x31, float x32); 

    std::vector<Node> const& nodes() const;
    std::vector<Edge> const& edges() const;
        [...]
    
private:

    std::vector<Node> m_nodes;
    std::vector<Edge> m_edges;
    [...]
};
```

So I parse a source file while constructing elementList

```
elementList::elementList(std::string filename)
{
        [...] //parse node coordinates from source file

        m_elements.emplace_back(element(x11,x12,x21,x22,x31,x32)); //1
}
```

The construction works, but what surprises me is that the address of top level variables in the element changes. If e.g. within the element constructor I print out

```
element::element(float x11, float x12, float x21, float x22, float x31, float x32)
{
        [...]
        std::cout << &m_nodes[0] << std::endl;
}
```

I get a different address than when I am in the elementList constructor and print out

```
elementList::elementList(std::string filename)
{
        [...]
        m_elements.emplace_back(element(x11,x12,x21,x22,x31,x32)); //1
        Node initialNode = m_elements.at(0).nodes().at(0);
        std::cout << &initialNode;
}
```

This consistently happens with all elements, only the addresses change, none of the node values. Is there a way to append an element to elementList and maintain the same memory address? Otherwise this would throw off some connectivity information I store within each individual element.

My guess is at step //1 the code actually copies the element instead of inserting it as is, is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: why is it a problem that the adress changes? Its not the adress of the elements that changes, but a copy is made and the two instances are stored at different address. There is nothing you can do about it. What is stored in a the vector cannot be the same object as one that is not stored in the vector.

Comment: `Node initialNode = ...` is creating a new, completely separate `Node` instance that is then copy-initialised with `m_elements.at(0).nodes().at(0)`. You're not printing the address of the object in vector.

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The vector needs to resize itself as you add new elements. That might reallocate all of the memory for the stored elements, invalidating pointers and iterators to individual elements.

Comment: "My guess is at step //1 the code actually copies the element " right that is what happens. `emplace` can avoid a copy, but only when you do not have an instance to begin with, as it constructs the instance in place. If you do have an instance then the only way to get it in the vector is to make a copy

Comment: @user12002570 Tip: You can use any of these: `[mcve]`, `[mre]`, `[reprex]`, `[repro]`, `[example]` to get link to [mcve] automagically. There a [bunch of other useful shorcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) too.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Oh man, I didn't know that. it will save me a lot of time. Thanks

Comment: The comment regarding `initialNode` helped! Using `&(m_elements.at(0).nodes().at(0))` directly gave me my original address again. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't add new items to `m_nodes` and `m_edges` after the element is constructed, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `elementList::elementList`:

```
Node initialNode = m_elements.at(0).nodes().at(0);
```

Notice that `initialNode` is a local variable, and its value is copy-initialized from `m_elements.at(0).nodes().at(0)`. That is, only the "value" in `Node` object is copied into `initialNode`.

So when you take the address (`&initialNode`), the value returned is the address of local variable `initialNode`, not the address of the object in `std::vector<Node>`. To take the address, use `&m_elements.at(0).nodes().at(0)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Adding elements to [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) may cause reallocation, which invalidates pointers to its elements.

You can use [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) instead. Adding and removing elements to/from the end of `std::deque` don't invalidate pointers except for the pointer to removed element.

Comment: Mention deque are not continguous.  Also should mention reserve.

Comment: The problem in the OP's code is that it is making a copy of a node into a local object, and then printing the address of the local object.